# How do I bcrypt password when inserting into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to create a user registration form using Laravel 4 but I am having trouble to bcrypt the password before inserting into the database. My sample code is as below.

Code at app/model/Register.php

```
    class Register extends Eloquent {


        protected $guarded = array();
        protected $table = 'login'; // table name
        public $timestamps = 'true' ; // to disable default timestamp fields

        // model function to store form data to database
        public static function saveFormData($data)
        {
            DB::table('login')->insert($data);
        }

}
```

Code at RegisterController.php

```
    public function store()
{
            $data =  Input::except(array('_token')) ;
            $rule  =  array(
                    'firstName'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
                    'lastName'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
                    'email'=>'required|email|unique:intern_login',
                    'password'=>'required|alpha_num|min:8'
                ) ;

            $validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);

            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                    return Redirect::to('register')
                            ->withErrors($validator->messages());
            }
            else
            {

                    Register::saveFormData(Input::except(array('_token')));

                    return Redirect::to('register')
                            ->withMessage('Data inserted');
            }
}
```

Code at routes.php

```
    Route::post('register_action', function()
{
        $obj = new RegisterController() ;
        return $obj->store();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see _any_ attempt at using `bcrypt` in your code … so what’s the actual “trouble”?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords), you have to use the `Hash::make` function.

```
$password = Hash::make('secret');
```

That said, your code extracts show that you don't have understood the way Laravel work. Have you read the documentation or any tutorial ?